# Return the (2n/3) element in a linked list while looping once on the list

Tags: java, oop, methods, linked-list, nodes

I'm working on a linked-list program, which allows me to loop over the list only once, and I can't copy the elements of the list to another data structure.

Suppose that the list is not empty (has at least one node) and the next of the last node is null.

The following method return the element at the index `(2n/3)` of a list of length `n`.

for example if `n=1` or `n=2` it returns the first element

if `n=3` or `n=4` it returns the second element.

I thought of keeping a temporary node that gets the next node if the number `(2n/3)` is an integer. 
Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    private int value;
    private LinkedListNode next;

    public LinkedListNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}

    public class ListUtils {

    public static LinkedListNode findTwoThirdsNode(LinkedListNode head){

        int length=0;
        LinkedListNode node=head.getNext();
        LinkedListNode tmp=head;
        double divresult=1;
        while (node!=null){
            length++;
            divresult=(2*length)/3;
            node=node.getNext();
            if (divresult%1==0){
                tmp=tmp.getNext();
            }

        }
        if (length==1 || length==2){
            return head;
        }
        else
            return tmp;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the rounding floored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by running over the linked list *twice*, but *interleaved* (in other words without a reset). You simply use a *rabbit-and-tortoise*-approach: you have the rabbit that hops three times per iteration, and the *tortoise* which hops twice each time:

```
LinkedListNode rabbit = head;
LinkedListNode tortoise = head;
while(rabbit != null) { //repeat until the rabit reaches the end of the list
    for(int i = 0; rabbit != null && i < 2; i++) {
        rabbit=rabbit.getNext(); //let the rabbit hop the first and second time
        if(rabbit != null) {
            tortoise=tortoise.getNext(); //let the tortoise hop the first and second time
        }
    }
    if(rabbit != null) {
        rabbit=rabbit.getNext(); //let the rabbit hop a third time
    }
}
return tortoise; //if reached the end, we return where the tortoise ended
```

If you want the result to be as close as possible to `2/3rd` (so not with much rounding errors), you better interleave the `rabbit` and `tortoise` hops as is done in the `for` loop. Furthermore you must do `null` checkings each time since it is possible that the length is not modulo three.

Answer (score 2):

Keep 2 pointers, when you go thru the loop progress the left of them only 2/3 of the time.

when you reach the end of the loop return the pointer to the other node.

```
int i = 0;
node temp = head;
node progress = head;
while(progress != null) {
 i++;
 progress = progress.next;
 if(i == 2 && progress != null) temp = temp.next;
 else if ( i == 3 && progress != null) {
  temp=temp.next;
  i=0;
 }
}
return temp;
}
```

this is the general idea

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple for loop?

```
int n = // ...
int index = 2 * n / 3;
LinkedListNode current = head;
for(int i = 0 ; i < index ; ++i) {
    current = current.next();
}
return current;
```

Comment: I think there is no length associated with the linked list, so you can *share* tails of linked lists together... Like is common in declarative languages like *Prolog* and *Haskell*...

Comment: I don't know what is n (the length of the list) from the beginning, also I have to loop only once over the list.

Comment: @Tam211: well you are only given a node and the node doesn't store the length. You could for instance construct a linked list `a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f`. Now you can calculate the `2/3` for `d` and for `a`. The point is that both use the same *nodes* and one can make modifications from one visible to the other. *n* is probably the length since there is no *n* given by the method. Nevertheless, it is a good solution (given you can calculate *n* fast) so +1.